# Leaflet.js - Can I add multiple holes/cutouts inside of a Single Polygon

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet, polygon, shapes

Looking over the documentation for the L.Polygon constructor, it looks like you can pass in multiple arrays of coordinates after the initial array to construct a Polygon, with multiple holes in it.

I tried a few small samples of data with multiple arrays, and the holes were shaded in after the first one was added.  But when one is added, it worked fine.

Coming from MSSQL, the shapes are reported as valid using the geometry::STIsValid function.

Is my data incorrect, or is this not supported at the time?
The documentation would suggest it is supported.  And every example I find on stackoverflow or the general internet only shows single holes.

This is also with the L.Polygon function (not GeoJSON).

Comment: Could you give an example of the array you pass to L.Polygon?

Comment: iH8, this has been answered and confirmed for me below. The issue seems to be with the UNION'ed shapes coming back from MSSQL for me.

Answer (score 8):

Looks to work with multiple holes:

```js
var coords = [
  [ // Exterior Ring
    [48.84, 2.3],
    [48.9, 2.3],
    [48.9, 2.4],
    [48.84, 2.4],
    [48.84, 2.3]
  ], // Then holes (interior rings)
  [ // First hole
    [48.85, 2.31],
    [48.89, 2.31],
    [48.89, 2.33],
    [48.85, 2.33],
    [48.85, 2.31]
  ],
  [ // Second hole
    [48.85, 2.34],
    [48.89, 2.34],
    [48.89, 2.35],
    [48.85, 2.35],
    [48.85, 2.34]
  ],
  [ // Third hole
    [48.85, 2.36],
    [48.89, 2.36],
    [48.89, 2.39],
    [48.85, 2.39],
    [48.85, 2.36]
  ]
];

L.polygon(coords).addTo(map);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/204/

[image]

Comment: On more recent version of leaflet, it forces me to have latLngs point. For that we can do: 
    L.polygon([coords.map((coords) => new L.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0])), coords2.map((coords) => new L.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]))]).addTo(this.map);

Comment: @Selorb thank you for your heads up! The above demo looks to work fine with Leaflet@1.9.4? https://jsfiddle.net/cv2j06mq/1/

Comment: You are right, that was true only on typescript. My bad

Comment: Strange, `@types/leaflet` should still have accepted `LatLngTuple[][]` https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/leaflet/index.d.ts#L2073

Comment: Ah I see, the issue is that the `coords` object is created beforehand and inferred by TS as `number[]` instead of tuple `[number, number]` => either assert type or inline value as litteral https://tsplay.dev/wjlP2m